# How to create an instance of ResourceManager object to get WinNT object?

Tags: c#, windows, resourcemanager

I am using `ResourceManager` in `Sytem.Resources` class of C#.ResourceManager has a protected constructor, so we cant create the instance directly. I want to use the GetObject function to get the object of WinNT.

I want to do the following :

```
 IADsOpenDSObject user= (IADsOpenDSObject)Utils.GetObject("WinNT:");
```

Details about IADsOpenDSObject is available in the following [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa706064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I tried doing the following :

```
    class ResourceManagerSub : ResourceManager
        {

            public ResourceManagerSub()
            {

            }
        }
    public class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ResourceManagerSub Utils = new ResourceManagerSub();
                IADsOpenDSObject user = (IADsOpenDSObject)Utils.GetObject("WinNT:");
                user.OpenDSObject("WinNT://machinename", Username, Password, (int)ADS_AUTHENTICATION_ENUM.ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION);


             }
      }
```

But I am getting exception : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

So how is it possible to instantiate `ResourceManager`?

Comment: The ResourceManager class is a million miles removed from COM and Active Directory Services.  The WinNT ADSI provider does not have any options to read managed resources from a program on another machine.  Putting them together makes no sense at all.

Comment: The following link gives the Visual Basic implementation to get the object and then use OpenDSObject to bind to the machine -[Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218497/en-us) .   How to get the object of WinNT?

Comment: Hard to see what that has to do with the code in the question.  I can only guess that you fell off this cliff by the usage of the word "Object" in ADS speak.  Does not have to anything at all with a .NET object or ResourceManager.GetObject().  The .NET Framework already has direct support for ADS, use the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

Comment: The following link provides VB implementation of the OpenDSObject method for LDAP provider.[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772136(v=vs.85).aspx).                                            I wanted to do the similar thing in C# with WinNT provider.